# Inequality involving the trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I need to prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for any $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, the following inequality holds:

$$tr^2\Big[(AA^T + I_n)^{-1}AA^T)\Big] 
\leq C \bigg[ tr^2\Big[A(A^TA+I_p)^{-1}A^T\Big] + tr\Big[A(A^TA+I_p)^{-1}A^T\Big] \bigg]$$

($C$ should be independent of $A$).

I thought of using the identity:

$$(AA^T + I_n)^{-1} = I_n - A(A^TA + I_p)^{-1}A^T$$

which transforms the LHS into something that is more similar to the RHS, but it gets me nowhere since I get:

$$tr^2\Big[(AA^T + I_n)^{-1}AA^T)\Big] = tr^2\Big[(I_n - A(A^TA + I_p)^{-1}A^T)AA^T\Big] $$

which becomes:

$$tr^2\Big[AA^T - A(A^TA + I_p)^{-1}A^TAA^T\Big] $$

which starts to look more similar to the RHS but I'm pretty stuck here for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for the moment that $n\ge p$. Observe that
\begin{cases}
(AA^T+I_n)^{-1}AA^T=I_n-(AA^T+I_n)^{-1},\\
(A^TA+I_p)^{-1}A^TA=I_p-(A^TA+I_p)^{-1}.
\end{cases}
Yet, if we perform a singular value decomposition $A=U\pmatrix{S\\ 0}V^T$, we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left((AA^T+I_n)^{-1}AA^T\right)
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(I_n-(AA^T+I_n)^{-1}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(I_n-\pmatrix{(S^2+I_p)^{-1}&0\\ 0&I_{n-p}}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(I_p-(S^2+I_p)^{-1}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((A^TA+I_p)^{-1}A^TA\right).
\end{align}
Therefore $(AA^T+I)^{-1}AA^T$ and $(A^TA+I)^{-1}A^TA$ have identical traces. If $n<p$, interchange the roles of $A$ and $A^T$ and the same conclusion holds.

So you may take $C=1$ in your inequality.